# Headset Cross Compatibility for PS4 and X1

Tags: ps4, xbox-one, audio-hardware

I'm currently the owner of the PlayStation 4 Pro, and I use the Astro A40 headset with the TR MixAmp.  I'm seriously considering getting the Xbox One X, and I'm wondering if my headset would be compatible (as is) with the new console.

I was under the impression that the TR MixAmp was *not* compatible with the Xbox One.  I'm assuming this is because the PS4 can accept microphone input through both USB and the 3.5mm jack on the controller.  This means I can either use the MixAmp and connect through USB, or just plug the headset itself directly into the controller through the 3.5mm jack.

The MixAmp provides obvious benefits, so I was wondering if anyone is aware of the Xbox One's capability to accept microphone input through USB instead of solely through the jack in the controller.  Can I use the TR MixAmp, or will I have to buy the MixAmp M80 to be able to use my Astro A40 headset w/ the Xbox One?

Answer (score -2):

It depends,I used to have a ps4 afterglow headset I would use on my xbox one and it kept breaking so then I got the xbox one version and it hasn't broken since,if it's not specifically for the ps4 and it plugs into the ps4 controller then it should work fine with the xbox one,but if its wireless and it has a bluetooth usb with it and also has a little audio plug jack that you can use on other devices then no it would break because it would get worn out and would interfere. I don't know this 100% but I'm pretty sure it would be okay.

Comment: You mean it would be okay to use the MixAmp, or simply use the headset plugged into the Xbox One controller?

Comment: only mixamp if u do use the headset and plug it into the controller it will break after a month or 2 btw sorry if this post was so late i totally forgot.